# SQL Query between 3 tables

Tags: sql, select, distinct, contains

I have 3 tables (note this may not be the best sql db design)

```
Room: TypeName, RoomNumber
RoomType: TypeName, ...
Reservation: StartDate, EndDate, TypeName, RoomNumber
```

My input parameters are `startdate` and `enddate`.  I'd like to know the distinct `roomtypes` available.  From my understanding the solution goes like this: `AvailableRoomTypes = AllRoomTypes - UnavailableRoomTypes`

Obviously `AllRoomTypes` can be found by: `SELECT DISTINCT(TypeName) FROM Room;`
and I know how to get unavailable rooms, but not unavailable `roomtypes`.  Nor do I know how to subtract one set from another.  I can get a set of all `rooms+roomtypes` and another set of unavailable `rooms+roomtypes` but how do I join them such that it is `A-B`?  Maybe some sort of `NOT_CONTAINS` function?

I'd like my output parameters to be `SELECT * FROM RoomType (for the appropriate roomtypes)`.

Comment: What database, and can you make it more obvious what is a table and what its columns are?

Comment: Here's what I have:
SELECT r.roomtype, s.servicename
  FROM RESERVATION r
  JOIN BILLING b ON b.reservationid = r.reservationid
             AND b.paid = 1
  JOIN Customer_SERVICE s ON s.customerserviceid = b.customerserviceid;

I need to sum billing.total for every distinct reservation.roomtype and customer_service.servicename.  So do I want to:
Select SUM(b.total) for reservations...
join
Select SUM(b.total) for services...
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unused RoomTypes

```
select RT.* 
from RoomType RT
where RT.TypeName not in (
   Select RM.TypeName 
   from Room RM
)
```

one way to do A-B selection is "not in (select ..)" operator, not exists (select ..) is another and there will be more, I am certain.

Comment: @Russ Cam: I don't know what a 'difference union' union is (Google indicates it doesn't either)! Would you care to post an answer to the OP's question that demonstrates a 'difference union'? But your point is taken, my reply sounds to absolute, as though 'not on' was the only way to solve the OP's question. Will rephrase!

Comment: difference union in tsql:

    SELECT blah blah blah
    EXCEPT
    SELECT blah blah blah

Comment: thanks it worked, that was the final logic I couldn't seem to find easily for some reason, even though it seems fairly basic

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM ROOMTYPE t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL 
                    FROM RESERVATION r
                    JOIN ROOM ro ON ro.roomnumber = r.roomnumber
                   WHERE ro.typename = t.typename
                     AND r.startdate BETWEEN ?IN_START_DATE AND ?IN_END_DATE
                     AND r.enddate BETWEEN ?IN_START_DATE AND ?IN_END_DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Room: TypeName, RoomNumber RoomType: TypeName, ... Reservation: StartDate, EndDate, TypeName, RoomNumber**

This may be your answer ... 
select rt.typename 
from room r,roomtype rt, reservation re
where r.typename=rt.typename 
and rt.typename=re.typename 
where re.startdate=:start_date 
and re.enddate=:endate

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a UNION - `SUM(reservation.roomtype)` and `SUM(service.servicetype)` are different attributes.  But if you did, you'd want to use NULLs to offset the queries so the columns don't overlap.  IE:

```
SELECT SUM(reservation.roomtype), NULL ...
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, SUM(service.servicetype) ...
```

Based on the logic you provided, this is the query I came up with:

```
SELECT SUM(r.roomtype),
       SUM(s.servicetype)
  FROM RESERVATION r
  JOIN BILL b ON b.reservationid = r.reservationid
             AND b.paid = 1
  JOIN SERVICE s ON s.serviceid = b.serviceid
```

That will return a single row.  We'd need to know what the query (or queries depending on the information) group on in order to return a more meaningful resultset.  The details of the `RESERVATION` and `SERVICE` tables would help us be able to help you.